# Automate layout design on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, cartography, layouts, visualisation, design

I have 100 different layouts, each zoomed to different polygons on the map. I would like to add two accompanying images, that are unique to each layout and positioned as shown in the screenshot below.

Is there a way to automate the process of adding, resizing and positioning the two images and my map frame as presented in my screenshot for each unique layout? It is currently very time consuming to do so for all 100 layouts.

I would also like to export all 100 layouts into jpegs at once. Currently I have to manually export each layout one by one.

[image]

Comment: To do this I would use ArcPy to emulate a Map Series so that you can insert the extra functionality into the code run for each page.